ESP-32 with DHT-11 sensor not returning the expected output
I am trying to use the output of a DHT sensor module whose data pin I have connected to Pin 27 of my ESP-32 Dev Module. The original code uses the DHT library but I can't seem to get that to work so I am using the DHT_nonblocking library which seems to work with my sensor. Here is example code from the DHT_nonblocking library that I tried to implement into my own code to create an asynchronous web server that displays the data. The example code worked, but my own code which I added direct lines from the example code is not returning any data from the DHT sensor.
Here are the codes:
EXAMPLE CODE that works with my sensor on an ESP-32:
#include <dht_nonblocking.h>

/* Uncomment according to your sensortype. */
#define DHT_SENSOR_TYPE DHT_TYPE_11
//#define DHT_SENSOR_TYPE DHT_TYPE_21
//#define DHT_SENSOR_TYPE DHT_TYPE_22

static const int DHT_SENSOR_PIN = 27;
DHT_nonblocking dht_sensor( DHT_SENSOR_PIN, DHT_SENSOR_TYPE );



/*
 * Initialize the serial port.
 */
void setup( )
{
 Serial.begin( 9600);
}



/*
* Poll for a measurement, keeping the state machine alive.  Returns
* true if a measurement is available.
*/
static bool measure_environment( float *temperature, float *humidity )
 {
  static unsigned long measurement_timestamp = millis( );

  /* Measure once every four seconds. */
  if( millis( ) - measurement_timestamp > 3000ul )
  {
    if( dht_sensor.measure( temperature, humidity ) == true )
    {
      measurement_timestamp = millis( );
      return( true );
    }
  }

  return( false );
}



/*
 * Main program loop.
 */
void loop( )
{
  float temperature;
  float humidity;

  /* Measure temperature and humidity.  If the functions returns
     true, then a measurement is available. */
  if( measure_environment( &temperature, &humidity ) == true )
   {
    Serial.print( "T = " );
    Serial.print( temperature, 1 );
    Serial.print( " deg. C, H = " );
    Serial.print( humidity, 1 );
    Serial.println( "%" );
  }
}


Here are my results by executing this code:
12:34:16.068 -> T = 26.0 deg. C, H = 6.0%
12:34:19.331 -> T = 26.0 deg. C, H = 6.0%
12:34:22.634 -> T = 27.0 deg. C, H = 6.0%
12:34:25.905 -> T = 27.0 deg. C, H = 6.0%
12:34:29.180 -> T = 27.0 deg. C, H = 6.0%
12:34:32.451 -> T = 27.0 deg. C, H = 6.0%
12:34:35.722 -> T = 28.0 deg. C, H = 7.0%
12:34:38.991 -> T = 28.0 deg. C, H = 7.0%
12:34:42.262 -> T = 28.0 deg. C, H = 7.0%
12:34:45.559 -> T = 28.0 deg. C, H = 7.0%
12:34:48.825 -> T = 29.0 deg. C, H = 8.0%
12:34:52.090 -> T = 29.0 deg. C, H = 8.0%
12:34:55.392 -> T = 30.0 deg. C, H = 8.0%
12:34:58.660 -> T = 31.0 deg. C, H = 9.0%
12:35:01.924 -> T = 31.0 deg. C, H = 9.0%
12:35:05.197 -> T = 31.0 deg. C, H = 9.0%
12:35:08.466 -> T = 32.0 deg. C, H = 9.0%

My code that gives a null result from the sensor:
 // Import required libraries
 #include <WiFi.h>
 #include "ESPAsyncWebServer.h"
 #include <dht_nonblocking.h>

// Replace with your network credentials
const char* ssid = "SSID";
const char* password = "PASSSWORD";

#define DHTPIN 27     // Digital pin connected to the DHT sensor

// Uncomment the type of sensor in use:
  #define DHTTYPE    DHT_TYPE_11     // DHT 11
//#define DHTTYPE    DHT22     // DHT 22 (AM2302)
//#define DHTTYPE    DHT21     // DHT 21 (AM2301)

DHT_nonblocking dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

// Create AsyncWebServer object on port 80
AsyncWebServer server(80);
static bool measure_environment( float *temperature, float *humidity )
{
  static unsigned long measurement_timestamp = millis( );

  /* Measure once every four seconds. */
  if( millis( ) - measurement_timestamp > 3000ul )
  {
    if( dht.measure( temperature, humidity ) == true )
    {
      measurement_timestamp = millis( );
      return( true );
    }
  }

  return( false );
}
  float temperature;
  float humidity;
String readDHTTemperature() {
    if( measure_environment( &temperature, &humidity ) == true )
  {
    Serial.print( "T = " );
    Serial.print( temperature, 1 );
    Serial.print( " deg. C");

    return String(temperature);



}}

String readDHTHumidity() {
     if( measure_environment( &temperature, &humidity ) == true )
  {

    Serial.print( "H = " );
    Serial.print( humidity, 1 );
    Serial.println( "%" );

    return String(humidity);



}}




const char index_html[] PROGMEM = R"rawliteral(
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
     html {
     font-family: Arial;
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 0px auto;
     text-align: center;
    }
    h2 { font-size: 3.0rem; }
    p { font-size: 3.0rem; }
    .units { font-size: 1.2rem; }
    .dht-labels{
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      vertical-align:middle;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>ESP32 DHT Server</h2>
  <p>
    <i class="fas fa-thermometer-half" style="color:#059e8a;"></i> 
    <span class="dht-labels">Temperature</span> 
    <span id="temperature">%TEMPERATURE%</span>
    <sup class="units">&deg;C</sup>
  </p>
  <p>
    <i class="fas fa-tint" style="color:#00add6;"></i> 
    <span class="dht-labels">Humidity</span>
    <span id="humidity">%HUMIDITY%</span>
    <sup class="units">&percnt;</sup>
  </p>
</body>
<script>
setInterval(function ( ) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("temperature").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "/temperature", true);
  xhttp.send();
}, 10000 ) ;

setInterval(function ( ) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("humidity").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "/humidity", true);
  xhttp.send();
}, 10000 ) ;
</script>
</html>)rawliteral";

// Replaces placeholder with DHT values
String processor(const String& var){
  //Serial.println(var);
  if(var == "TEMPERATURE"){
    return readDHTTemperature();
  }
  else if(var == "HUMIDITY"){
    return readDHTHumidity();
  }
  return String();
}

void setup(){
  // Serial port for debugging purposes
  Serial.begin(115200);

//  dht.begin();

  // Connect to Wi-Fi
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }

  // Print ESP32 Local IP Address
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  // Route for root / web page
  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/html", index_html, processor);
  });
  server.on("/temperature", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", readDHTTemperature().c_str());
  });
  server.on("/humidity", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", readDHTHumidity().c_str());
  });

  // Start server
  server.begin();
}

void loop(){

}

Here are my results by running this code:
     12:27:40.469 -> Connecting to WiFi..
     12:27:40.469 -> 10.0.0.236
     12:27:47.375 -> T = 0.0 deg. CH = 0.0%
     12:28:32.344 -> T = 0.0 deg. CH = 0.0%
     12:29:32.312 -> T = 0.0 deg. CH = 0.0%
     12:30:32.378 -> T = 0.0 deg. CH = 0.0%

Why is this happening?
The wiring, baud rate of the Serial Monitor is right, and I have tried everything from this website: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/solved-dht11-dht22-failed-to-read-from-dht-sensor/, but the output keeps saying the temperature and the humidity are 0 or null. How can I change the code which creates a web server to give the right results? Thanks!
(Sorry for any bad grammar or formatting. Let me know if you need any more details. Thanks again!)

If the hardware setup did not change between both sets of code, then we can  narrow down the issue to the code rather than a hardware fault.
The fact that the zero-value is being printed out hints to me that the global variables (which are zero initialized) are not being changed.
A possible issue could be the use of temperature and humidity as global variables. Unless there is a good reason to have them as globals, maybe remove them and bring them into the function's local scope, similar to how the example code (that you tested that works) did it:
String readDHTHumidity() {
     float temperature;
     float humidity;
     if( measure_environment( &temperature, &humidity ) == true ) {
        Serial.print( "H = " );
        Serial.print( humidity, 1 );
        Serial.println( "%" );
        return String(humidity);
     }
}

I don't have the physical setup so its hard for me to test the code itself - but if the above doesn't work, you can try placing more Serial print statements (or use a debugger) inside the measure_environment function to see if the value of temperature & humidity actually changes after being passed into the dht functions. From there you can trace and see at which point in the chain of functions the values fail to be updated.
Hope this helps you in your debugging!

Thanks, but now I am getting a different output that also does not make sense.
Connecting to WiFi...
10.0.0.236
T = 0.0 deg. C, H = 0.0%
T = 0.0 deg. C, H = -0.0%
T = 0.0 deg. C, H = -0.0%
T = 0.0 deg. C, H = -0.0%
T = 0.0 deg. C, H = 0.0%
T = 0.0 deg. C, H = 0.0%
The humidity values are randomly switching from 0 to -0, and the output data still is not accurate. Anything else I can do to troubleshoot this?
The program also seems to randomly stop working and it stops returning values completely when I use the code with the variables in the local method scope. Any solution?

Perhaps it is the way the AsyncWebServer processes the functions. A few ideas you can try: Do a sanity check - measure_env() in the setup func (before the server logic) and check if the values are as expected. If it works, then it's plausibly the function issue. Instead of passing readDHTHumidity().c_str() as a parameter, create a local scope string first then pass it in. The idea is to move parts of the function INTO the lambda rather than pass it in send_P since scoping seems to be an issue. You can try tinkering with the capture list too.
